# Java alternative to multiple inheritance

Tags: java, oop

Since I know Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, I'd like to know how could I implement this design in Java:

```
Class StudentModel extends BaseModel{
   public void doSomething(){};
}
Class ParentModel{
   protected List<BaseModel> children = new List<BaseModel>();
   public void addChild(BaseModel child){
      children.add(child);
   }
   // and other parent-children related functionality
}

Class ConcreteParentModel{
    // should contain both StudentModel and ParentModel functionalily
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can `implement` multiple interfaces, but only `extend` a single class.

Comment: You could use interfaces with (shudder) default methods.

Comment: You can always use composition instead of inheritance.  Just make `ConcreteParentModel` have a parent and a student and have wrapper methods that pass the call to the appropriate instance variable.

Comment: What I aim to achieve is just less code. Implementing interfaces wouldn't do the job. I'll have to implement parent-related methods for every other class that also should be a "parent".
Also a wrapper wouldn't do the job since i'll have to write the wrapper code for every derived class that should also be a parent.

Comment: If you want to write less code, use a language designed for that purpose - there are other languages on the JVM that may interest you. Java (the language) is designed for clean and robust code, not short code.

Comment: Hi @Gimby, What other languages can I use on Delvik VM? (Android)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [adapter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm) pattern

In software engineering, the adapter pattern is a software design pattern that allows the interface of an existing class to be used from another interface. It is often used to make existing classes work with others without modifying their source code.

Comment: Thanks, but this would not help me to end with less code. I plan to add more other concrete classes that derive from other classes but all have this "parent" functionality.

Comment: Ok.  I would implement a combination of adapters and [strategy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) patterns then.  In Strategy pattern, we create objects which represent various strategies and a context object whose behavior varies as per its strategy object. The strategy object changes the executing algorithm of the context object.

Comment: I'm afraid this wouldn't help as well. I need all the inherited methods to be visible for Jackson via @JsonProperty

Comment: Unfortunately your only real solution is to use adapters.